# Modifying shortcuts for Android emulator

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, keyboard-shortcuts

Is there a way to modify the default shortcuts used by the Android emulator? The help shows the fixed set of keys we can use, but doesn't seem to provide a way to change them.

Comment: Yes, it is possible to modify the default shortcuts used by the Android emulator. You can do this by creating a new profile in the emulator's settings, and then customizing the shortcuts for that profile. You can also use third-party software to remap the keys on your keyboard to emulate the shortcuts you want to use.